# How do I list available trade routes

Tags: civilization-6

Civilization V had a way to list all available trade routes:

[image: Available trade routes in Civilization V]

I haven't found anything similar in Civilization VI, and no help when googling.

I found this *very* useful in Civilization V, is there something similar in Civilization VI?

Comment: How do you open that Trade Route Overview menu? Nvm, found it: top right bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the release of the [Rise and Fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_VI:_Rise_and_Fall) expansion, it is now possible to review avaialble trade routes.

Just click the trade routes button (the circle of two arrows) in the top right menu:

[image: Available trade routes]

Answer (score 2):

You can view trade routes for cities which currently have an idle trader in them on the `trade route overview` (icon in the top right) and selecting the `available trade route` tab.

There is (currently) no way to view all available trade routes in **all** cities. (I agree this is a feature the developers should implement soon)

Comment: Although it is hard to prove this, I have to agree with you. The place where it should be is the place you are pointing out here. Hope they fix it.

Comment: Due to the merging of land/water trading compared to Civ V, I find the current trading overview a bit daunting (mid game and later, many cities in reach). Even just thinking about having to use a full list of all possibilities from all cities just makes me sweaty and dizzy. Or am I grossly underestimating gameplay depth for trading?

Comment: See my answer for an update since the Rise and Fall expansion.